# Dynamic router advertising on IPv6

Tags: ipv6, radvd, icmpv6

I have a problem that I'm hoping I can solve with IPv6 but since I haven't had a chance to try it yet I thought I'd propose my solution here.

My problem is that we have a LAN with a number of devices that have internal Wifi. All of them are capable of connecting to another access point to get internet access and I want to provide that access to the rest of the network. I'm thinking that:

- I implement IPv6 SLAAC on all devices.
- If a device connects to the internet via Wifi it announces itself to the rest of the wired network using Router Advertising (using [radvd](http://www.litech.org/radvd/) or something similar).
- If it's disconnected from the internet then it stops advertising.

From my research it seems that IPv6 is fine with just SLAAC on a network and can handle multiple routers being advertised. What I'm not sure is whether it can handle routers being added and removed dynamically like this. I see that a router that is not default can set a lifetime of 0. Will this achieve what I want? Are their other issues I will encounter?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, (at least to me) it's not clear what you are trying to do.  Can you perhaps edit your post with a diagram ?

Also, if you are trying to "share" IPv6, it doesn't really work the same way as the IPv4 world (i.e. NAT, and there is IPv6 NAT, but that's another story...)

If you run radvd on a host that's dual homed, how will that host's upstream know to send the prefix to it ?  You'd have to have your ISP router routing a /64 or more to the connected address of the host, and then the host could be an intermediate router.  None of this is easy, automatic or (in my opinion) very clean.  You can do things with multiple layers of DHCP-PD I suppose, but again, we are back to a lot of complexity and possibly fragility.